# AS3 multitouch end touch error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have some AS3 code that works for multi touch, but i have a tiny problem,
here are my eventListners

```
    private function onTouchBegin( e:TouchEvent ):void
    {
        //Move the touch locations
        //touchX = e.stageX;
        //touchY = e.stageY;
        m_oTouchIDs[e.touchPointID] = new Point(e.stageX, e.stageY);
    }

    private function onTouchMove( e:TouchEvent ):void
    {
        //touchX = e.stageX;
        //touchY = e.stageY;
        var p:Point = m_oTouchIDs[e.touchPointID] as Point;
        p.x = e.stageX;
        p.y = e.stageY;
        //removeEventListener( TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, onTouchMove );
    }

    private function onTouchEnd( e:TouchEvent ):void
    {
        //touchX = -100;
        //touchY = -100;

        delete m_oTouchIDs[e.touchPointID]; // release
    }
```

now if i place my finger onto a button, it will work, but if i release my finger, it still thinks my finger is touching that button, any idea why my delete function is not working? if you want more code just ask

Canvas

Comment: Perhaps the delete is working but this isn't triggering an update to the UI?

Comment: I don't think it is, how would i get the object in the object variable and change its X and Y manually? that could work